# Magento2 admin page 'ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS' error. magento version (2.2.2)

Tags: magento2

I am facing below error for admin page

> ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS error

I am having base url as http://staging.manohar.com.

Comment: I have get any solutions for this. I am getting this error on frontend too with multiple store.

Answer (score 0):

If your website frontend is working on https:// but redirect loop in admin panel, below is the reason.

- Magento checks 2 request header when you send a request to admin
  HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO and HTTPS
- If you are not sending these request header, magento tries to redirect http in admin.
- Then check web/secure/use_in_adminhtml config. if it is 1, want to redirect https again.

Set below parameters in apache for https and it will be solved.

```
SetEnv HTTPS "on"
SetEnv HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO "https"
```